# Evaluate $\int \frac {\operatorname d\!x} {2x \sqrt{1-x}\sqrt{2-x + \sqrt{1-x}}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

$$\int \dfrac {\operatorname d\!x} {2x \sqrt{1-x}\sqrt{2-x + \sqrt{1-x}}}$$

Hey there, I've got this complicated integral to evaluate, but I don't know how to go about. I have tried making two substitutions:

1. $ t^2 = 1 - x $
2. $ x = \sin^2\theta $

But both gave another complicated integral to evaluate:

$$ \int \dfrac {\operatorname d\!t} {(t^2-1)\sqrt{ t^2 + t + 1 }} $$

I tried to get the answer for this one using wolfram alpha, but it gave a **HUGE**, simply **HUGE** solution. I also tried to get the solution for the original question via wolfram alpha, but it timed out.

Any ideas?

Comment: Where does the integral come from? Do you need the full analytic solution?

Comment: We had this as a test question. But now I have started doubting that there might be some error in the question, don't know though because no one had announced that there was any error in the question paper.

Comment: No, hints will do, as they almost always do in my questions :D (don't know what you mean by full *analytic* solution though!)

Comment: Mathematica gives for first integral this: $\frac12\left(\frac{\log(1-\sqrt{1-x})}{\sqrt3}-\log(1+\sqrt{1-x})+\log(1-\sqrt{1-x}+2\sqrt{2+\sqrt{1-x}-x})-\frac{\log(3+3\sqrt{1-x}+2\sqrt3\sqrt{2+\sqrt{1-x}-x})}{\sqrt3}\right)$

Comment: You are getting a log. Means : USE partial fractions. Seems absurd, though.

Comment: @Parth: If it wasn't a test question that was known to be solvable, I'd suggest numerics, a definite integral or an approximation, rather than a long tedious formula with lots of stupid things that don't make any sense or matter! That's what I meant (: The above answer looks awful.

Comment: @Sharkos, I know, it looks so aweful. With all these responses, I seriously suspect it's a wrong question! And yes, agreed it'd be better to have an approximation if it was a 'real-world' problem!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For what it's worth, you can break things up a bit by recognizing that

$$\frac{1}{t^2-1} = \frac12 \left ( \frac{1}{t-1} - \frac{1}{t+1}\right )$$

For example, consider the $t-1$ piece; you may substitute $u=t+1/2$ and get

$$\int \frac{dt}{(t-1) \sqrt{t^2+t+1}} = \int \frac{du}{(u-3/2) \sqrt{u^2+3/4}}$$

This latter integral is relatively tame [according to WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5B1/%28%28u-3/2%29%20Sqrt%5Bu%5E2%2b3/4%5D%29%20,%20u%5D&t=crmtb01):

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \left[\log{\left(u-\frac{3}{2}\right)}-\log{\left(\sqrt{12 u^2+9}+3 u+\frac{3}{2}\right)}\right]+C$$

where $C$ is a constant of integration.  A similar expression may be found for the $t+1$ piece.

Comment: I think that's a good way to go...!

Answer (score 5):

The following integral

$$ \int \frac{1}{x \sqrt{ax^2 + bx + c}}\text{d}x$$

can be solved by substituting $x = \frac{1}{t}$ to get

$$\int \frac{\pm 1}{\sqrt{a + bt + ct^2}}\text{d}t$$

Which can be recast as the derivative of an inverse trigonometric function (could be hyperbolic, depending on the signs taken):

$$\int \frac{\pm 1}{\sqrt{\pm 1 \pm x^2}}$$

And as noted by Ron, your integral is the sum of two such integrals.

Answer (score 1):

The $t$-integral is primed for the well-known [Euler substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution). Let

$$u=\frac{\sqrt{t^2+t+1} - 1}t \implies t  = -\frac{1-2u}{1-u^2} \implies dt = \frac{2u^2-2u+2}{(1-u^2)^2} \, du$$

to transform to

$$\begin{align*}
I &= \int \dfrac{dt}{(t^2-1)\sqrt{ t^2 + t + 1 }} \\[1ex]
&= 2 \int \frac{u^2 - u + 1}{(1-u^2)^2 \left(\frac{(1-2u)^2}{(1-u^2)^2} - 1\right) \left(1-\frac{u-2u^2}{1-u^2}\right)} \, du \\[1ex]
&= 2 \int  \frac{u^2-1}{u(u-2)(u^2+2u-2)} \, du
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 1):

Apply the Euler substitution $\sqrt{t^2+t+1}=(t+\frac12)y+\frac{\sqrt3}2$.

\begin{align}
& \int \frac1{(t^2-1)\sqrt{ t^2 + t + 1 }} \ dt\\
=&\int \frac{2}{3y^2+2\sqrt3 y-3} + \frac{2}{y^2-2\sqrt3 y-1} \ dy\\
=& -\frac1{\sqrt3}\tanh^{-1}\frac{\sqrt3 y+1}{2}-\tanh^{-1}\frac{y-\sqrt3}{2}\\
=&\ -\frac1{\sqrt3}\tanh^{-1}\frac{\sqrt3 \sqrt{t^2+t+1}+t-1}{2t+1}
- \tanh^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{t^2+t+1}-\sqrt3(t+1)}{2t+1}
\end{align}